# How to ask if a string variable can be parsed to an int variable?

Tags: c#, parsing

What can I use that will return a boolean variable that will state if I can parse a string safely or not?

1847 will return true
18o2 will return false

And please, nothing too complicated...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

```
int result = 0;
bool success = int.TryParse("123", out result);
```

*Here success will have true if parsed successfully and false other wise and result will have parse int value.*

Answer (score 2):

Use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx):

```
int i;
bool canBeParsed = int.TryParse("1847", out i);
if(canBeParsed)
{
    Console.Write("Number is: " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "18o2"
int num = 0;

bool canBeParsed = Int32.TryParse(str, out num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/f02979c7.aspx) method

Answer (score 1):

I have been using these extension methods for years. Maybe a bit more "complicated" in the beginning but their use is very simple. You can extend most of the simple values types including `Int16`, `Int64`, `Boolean`, `DateTime`, etc. using a similar pattern.

```
using System;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static Int32? AsInt32(this string s)
        {
            Int32 result;       
            return Int32.TryParse(s, out result) ? result : (Int32?)null;
        }

        public static bool IsInt32(this string s)
        {
            return s.AsInt32().HasValue;
        }

        public static Int32 ToInt32(this string s)
        {
            return Int32.Parse(s);
        }
    }
}
```

To use these, just include `MyLibrary` in the list of namespaces with a `using` declaration.

```
"1847".IsInt32(); // true
"18o2".IsInt32(); // false

var a = "1847".AsInt32();
a.HasValue; //true

var b = "18o2".AsInt32();
b.HasValue; // false;

"18o2".ToInt32(); // with throw an exception since it can't be parsed.
```